# Picturebox Panning Boundary inside Panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, picturebox, boundary

My image is inside the panel, I set up a if-statement for the boundary which it can only be moved. When I tried to run it, it looks crappy when the mouse has panned it outside the boundary. Here is my code for panning:

```
If (mouse.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then

  Dim mousePosNow As Point = mouse.Location

  Dim deltaX As Integer = mousePosNow.X - mouseDowns.X
  Dim deltaY As Integer = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDowns.Y

  Dim newX As Integer
  Dim newY As Integer

  If PictureBox1.Location.X <= Panel1.Location.X And PictureBox1.Location.Y <= Panel1.Location.Y And _
  (PictureBox1.Location.X + PictureBox1.Width) >= (Panel1.Location.X + Panel1.Width) And _
  (PictureBox1.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Height) >= (Panel1.Location.Y + Panel1.Height) Then

    newX = PictureBox1.Location.X + deltaX
    newY = PictureBox1.Location.Y + deltaY
  End If

  PictureBox1.Location = New Point(newX, newY)

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you've got your PictureBox *inside* your Panel, then you don't need to account for the Panel's location, since the PictureBox's location will be zeroed at the top-left of the Panel.

This condition:

```
If PictureBox.Location.X <= Panel1.Location.X ...
```

should be changed to this condition:

```
If PictureBox.Location.X <= 0
```

Also, the problem you're running into is due to that fact that your event-handler is flipping between moving the PictureBox from 0,0 to moving the PictureBox to the delta location.

E.g: 
When you drag the PictureBox towards the right such that it's left boundary goes past the Panel's left boundary (i.e. PictureBox.Location.X > 0) then the condition of your if-statement evaluates to False and the PictureBox's location is set to 0. However, since you've now changed its location, the MouseMove event is triggered again and this time the condition of your if-statement evaluates to True and the PictureBox's location is set to the delta location. 
Once again the MouseMove event is triggered and the scenario repeats, flipping the PictureBox's location back and forth, causing a jittering effect.

You can fix this by changing your condition to rely on the new location of the PictureBox, instead of the current location:

This condition:

```
If PictureBox.Location.X <= 0 ...
```

should be changed to this condition:

```
If (PictureBox.Location.X + deltaX) <= 0 ...
```

This fixes the jittering problem but your code only takes care of the case where the PictureBox is dragged towards the right and bottom.

Instead of writing more conditions, you could simplify your code by moving the calculations into a separate function that handles each axis separately:

```
If (mouse.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then

  Dim mousePosNow As Point = mouse.Location

  Dim deltaX As Integer = mousePosNow.X - mouseDowns.X
  Dim deltaY As Integer = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDowns.Y

  Dim newX As Integer = Clamp(PictureBox1.Location.X + deltaX, PictureBox1.Width, Panel1.Width)
  Dim newY As Integer = Clamp(PictureBox1.Location.Y + deltaY, PictureBox1.Height, Panel1.Height)

  PictureBox1.Location = New Point(newX, newY)
End If

...

Private Function Clamp(val As Integer, outerBound As Integer, innerBound As Integer) As Integer
  Dim newVal As Integer = val

  If newVal > 0 Then
    newVal = 0
  End If

  If newVal + outerBound < innerBound Then
    newVal = innerBound - outerBound
  End If

  Return newVal
End Function
```